# Google Cloud Messaging- Sending Push Message To Android Using PHP

Tags: php, android, html, json, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on an android project where I need to push messages using GCM. 
I wanna send the notification using only PHP and not HTML. How do I achieve this? The way I tried was just putting the gcm_regid and message as parameters to $gcm->send_notification($registration_ids,$msg) but I keep getting an error saying:-
Field "data" must be a JSON array: ["You Have A Notification!"]

Where "You Have A Notification!" is my msg!! Please help!! Thanks!

Code for send_notification is

```
 public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {

    include_once './config.php';

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}

}
```

This is the index.php used for sending the message using the button's on-click. I need to however do this automatically in the background without any button press and want to implement it in PHP.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        });
        function sendPushNotification(id){
            var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
            $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
            $.ajax({
                url: "send_message.php",
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                      $('.txt_message').val("");
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container{
            width: 950px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
        }
        h1{
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: #777;
        }
        div.clear{
            clear: both;
        }
        ul.devices{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        ul.devices li{
            float: left;
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #dedede;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0 15px 25px 0;
            border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #555;
        }
        ul.devices li label, ul.devices li span{
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-variant: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #393939;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }
        ul.devices li label{
            height: 25px;
            width: 50px;                
        }
        ul.devices li textarea{
            float: left;
            resize: none;
        }
        ul.devices li .send_btn{
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0096FF), to(#005DFF));
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #0096FF, #005DFF);
            background: linear-gradient(#0096FF, #005DFF);
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            border-radius: 3px;
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $users = $db->getAllUsers();
    if ($users != false)
        $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
    else
        $no_of_users = 0;
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>No of Devices Registered: <?php echo $no_of_users; ?></h1>
        <hr/>
        <ul class="devices">
            <?php
            if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                ?>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row["id"] ?>')">
                            <label>Name: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <label>Email:</label> <span><?php echo $row["email"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="send_container">                                
                                <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
                                <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Send" onclick=""/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                <?php }
            } else { ?> 
                <li>
                    No Users Registered Yet!
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have u successfully send notification using answer given below i m also facing same issue

Comment: @user3233280 Yes! This was a long time ago so don't quite remember the location but I think the GCM PHP had a parameter in the send message function called price which needed to be changed to my variable name set in android receiving function. 
Hope I am clear!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    'data' => array("message" => $message),
);
```

Comment: Seems to be the solution but it doesn't send the message. It sends a blank message not the specified message. I will try to figure that out! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to embed the registration_id too in array.

```
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => array($registatoin_ids),
    'data' => array("message" => $message),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fields[] = array(
            'registration_ids' =>$registatoin_ids,
            'data' =>$message
        );
```

use square braces with $fields this will make it a json array